# In Lodash.js/Underscore.js, how to add index for every element?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Here is the input:

```
[{animal: "cat"}, {animal:"dog}}
```

And the output would be :

```
[{animal: "cat", idx: 1}, {animal: "dog", idx: 2}]
```

Does anyone have ideas about how to do this in Lodash/Underscore.js?

Comment: `_.map(input, function(x, i) { return _.extend({idx:i}, x); })`?

Answer (score 3):

**In Underscore:**

You could use either ***.map*** or **.each** to iterate across every element in the target array you were looking to add indexes to. Then you could use **_.extend** to add the "idx" prop.

**Working Example:**

```
var data =  [{animal: "cat"}, {animal:"dog"}]

_.map(data, function(e, i) {
  return _.extend(e, {idx: i + 1});
});
```

Comment: @torazaburo You are correct as the OP wants to start his index at 1. Updated my answer.

Comment: When using `map()`, it's best to not mutate each item in the collection. I would change it to `return _.extend({ idx: i + 1 }, e)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{animal: "cat"}, {animal:"dog"}, {animal:"er"}];
var data2 = _.select(data,function(val, key){    
    return {val, idx : key};
});
```

Comment: I'm not getting this at all. I guess `select` is an old name for `filter`, but your filter function is always returning a truthy value, so all items will be selected, and you'll end up with what you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Loop across the elements, adding the index to each.

```
_.each(data, function(elt, i) { elt.idx = i + 1; })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newAnimals = _.map(animals, function(animal, index){
    animal.idx = index + 1;
    return animal;
})
```